# Check if a username is in a database using python and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to check if a username is in a database using python and SQLite3, here's my code

```
name = request.form.get("username")
namecheck = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?", (name))
if name in namecheck:
    return apology("Username already exists")
```

Sorry, I'm still pretty new to this, why isn't this working?

Comment: You need to change `(name)` to `(name,)` in `db.execute(...` line. Also `namecheck` will be cursor object

Comment: `(name)` is just the same data type as `name`, it's just an expression in parentheses. If you add a comma, it becomes a tuple of 1 value, `(name,)`

Comment: Thanks, I added the comma and changed my if statement a bit and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you are using is wrong here.  Most typically you should be calling `db.execute()` as a void function.  Then, you should be iterating the `db` object to get the records.  That being said, I would use an exists query here:

```py
name = request.form.get("username")
sql = 'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = ?)'
db.execute(sql, (name,))
if db.fetchone()[0]:
    return apology("Username already exists")
```

Comment: I tried using your method and was getting back "AttributeError: 'SQL' object has no attribute 'fetchone''" I think it's because I'm using the cs50 library.  I figured it out in the end using my code and  "if not namecheck ==[]:" Thanks for your help though!